# How can I customised alert boxes for both mobile and desktop display from this code?

Tags: javascript, alert

I am quite new to JS and, although enjoying, am finding it difficult to get syntax correct.

I wanted to customise my alert boxes with my own version of them, and it seemed easy enough. I found a neat tutorial [here](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Alert-Box-Programming-Tutorial) and ran it successfully, did a bit of styling and found it wasn't very mobile friendly.

The main issue stems from two parts of the code, CSS here:

```
    #dialogbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: #0b6623;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 550px;
  z-index: 2001;
}
```

Firstly, the dialogue box is set to 550px, which is fine on a large screen. The real issue occurs when you run the script which sets the position of the dialogue box:

```
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        let winW = window.innerWidth;
        let winH = window.innerHeight;
        let dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        let dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = '<strong>Share your score to Facebook</strong>';
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Alert.ok()"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Close</button>';
    }
    this.ok = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
let Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

There are lines there that set the box directly into the centre of the screen.

My question is - I still want centre screen but I want the dialogue box to be fluid and shrink down to size on a mobile phone. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this with that CSS?

The full script is available here: https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Alert-Box-Programming-Tutorial

Thanks kindly :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay last attempt to help here.
The sample code below behaves exactly the same as the built in browser alert dialog boxes. It puts the box in the middle, auto sizes according to the content, and anything else on the page is NOT clickable or editable until the dialog box is closed.  Well I wrote is a while back and I don't see any difference. It should work on any device so use it, change it, style it however you want. Note the "DO NOT CHANGE" comments. Changing that defeats the purpose. You do need the JQuery.js so download the the latest one here https://jquery.com/download/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    
    .main-container{
        display: flex;    /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        height: 100vh;    /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        width: 100%;      /* DO NOT CHANGE */
    }

    .c-message{
        display: flex;    /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        position: fixed;  /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        top: 0px;         /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        left: 0px;        /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        width: 100%;      /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        height: 100%;     /* DO NOT CHANGE */
    }

    .c-msgbox{
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto; /* DO NOT CHANGE */
        background-color: #e4e4e4;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #adadad;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    }

    .standerd-button2{
        border: none;
        font-family: arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: white;
        background: #1A709F;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        width: max-content;
        min-width: 50px;
        margin: 2px;
    }

    .standerd-button2:hover{
        background: crimson;
        cursor: default;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <div>
        <a id="ok" href="#">Normal Alert</a>
        <br>
        <a id="yn" href="#">Yes/No Alert</a>
    </div>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.fn.CustomAlert = function (options, callback) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            message: null,
            detail: null,
            yesno: false,
            okaytext: null,
            yestext: null,
            notext: null
        }, options);

        var frm = "";
        detail = "<b>" + settings.detail + "</b>";
        message = "<b>" + settings.message + "</b>";
        if (settings.detail === null) {
            detail = "";
        };

        frm = frm + message + "<div style='text-align: left; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;'>" + detail + "</div>";

        if (settings.yesno === false) {
            frm = frm + "<input id='ok' type='button' value='" + settings.okaytext + "' class='standerd-button2' />";
        } else {
            frm = frm + "<div><input id='yes' type='button' value='" + settings.yestext + "' name='yes' class='standerd-button2' />" +
                        "<input id='no' type='button' value='" + settings.notext + "' name='no' class='standerd-button2' /></div>";
        };

        var frmesg = "<div id='cmessage' name='cmessage' class='c-message'>" +
                     "<div class='c-msgbox'>" +
                     "<form>" + frm + "</form>" +
                     "</div>" +
                     "</div>";

        $(".main-container").append(frmesg);

        if (!settings.yesno) {
            $("#cmessage #ok").click(function () {
                $("#cmessage").remove();
                callback(false);
            });
        } else {
            $("#cmessage #yes").click(function () {
                $("#cmessage").remove();
                callback(true);
            });
            $("#cmessage #no").click(function () {
                $("#cmessage").remove();
                callback(false);
            });
        };
    };

    $("#yn").click(function(){
        $().CustomAlert({message: "<div style='text-align: left;'><p><b>Confirmation Alert</b></p></div>",
                       yestext: "Yes",
                       notext: "No",
                       yesno: true},
                       function(success){
                           if (success) {
                               null;
                               // Do something
                           } else {
                               null;
                               // Do something else
                               
                       };
        });
    });

    $("#ok").click(function(){
        $().CustomAlert({message: "<div style='text-align: left;'><p><b>Bla bla bla</b></p></div>",
                       okaytext: "Continue",
                       yesno: false},
                       function(success){
                           if (success) {
                               null;
                               // Do something
                        
                       };
        });
    });    
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will definitely use this in future projects! This is a great set of code! Thank you!

Comment: Anytime. My pleasure.

Comment: Nice having confirm as well as alert. I'd like to try it out in my code but I don't know jquery so have got a bit stuck on how do I put a call to the function in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media Queries. Give your modal dialog a different style on mobile, tablet and desktop if needed. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 #dialogbox {
    /* your mobile styles */
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
 #dialogbox {
     /* your mobile styles */
  }
}

#dialogbox {
     /* your normal styles */
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to do it that way, so it does make sense. I was using Bootstrap too, so I was thinking of ways to beat it in Bootstrap, but I had tried media queries before... but I think I will re-visit that again. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Oh... wait, I remember the issue... it won't display properly because of the JS. I am unsure how to set the JS to the same proportions especially this line ` dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px"; `

Answer (score 0):

Use vh and vw.
These are view width and height, relative to the browser window.
One unit equals 1% of the browser width or height.

Use vh and vw if you want to set specific width and heights.
But I would suggest having all your content in a main div with a css style  `"display: flex;"` and your actual dialogue box(div) size not specified but just with a css property of `"margin: auto;"`.

This will center it and automatically be sized according to your content in the box.
But then again, if you want to specify a size you can still then use vw and vh.
Up to you.

Comment: ok, sounds reasonable. I have to take out that JS line dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";

And then? Should I just use vh and vw in CSS then?

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for the response. It's being more of a pain than I imagined. I was so happy when I found that tutorial and then devastated when I discovered the lack of display on a mobile. Any idea what I should do then?

Comment: Apologies, I have removed my original comment which was incorrect. vw/vh are the dimensions of the viewport, not to be confused with the browser's window,  so the answer here is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with this function in JS but removed one line and its variable:

```
let winW = window.innerWidth;
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
```

The CSS had some changes too:

```
#dialogbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 17.5%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #0b6623;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 67.7%;
  max-width: 550px;
  z-index: 2001;
}
```

It's not perfect, granted, but it is 10s of 1000s of times better than before.

For those wondering why a z-index of 2001, because I am using bootstrap modals and they have a z-index of 1040 or so. And the z-index of 2000 is taken up by the white overlay (see code in OP).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suggest, if what I think you want is correct.
Copy this below and test it.
If it is not what you need, sorry, just tried to help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-container{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.dialogbox{
    display: flex; 
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);    
}

.dialogbox .dialogtext{
    margin: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="dialogbox">
        <span class="dialogtext">
            <h3>Some text</h3>
        </span> 
    </div>  
<div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer has become somewhat discursive, in terms of answering the question as set, the use of CSS vw/vh and media queries as recommended by other contributors will solve the immediate problem. I have left this answer here though as pondering the question raised additional issues of 'what are we trying to do with an alert function?'

The alert function in Javascript has some characteristics that you cannot emulate in your own Javascript, but you can get close.

The main thing about alert is that it is just that, the user is informed no matter what else is going on so it sits on top. It can get 'lost' in the middle of a wide window if the window is partially off the screen.

On most mobiles though it's a bit better because normally if your code is running the window will be at least partially visible on the screen.

For your immediate question, the best bet for making the alert box be visible, is to use the viewport dimensions plus fixed (as you have done)- the given code uses window dimensions and that just isn't going to work in all cases - the alert box could be way off the screen - for example if the window is representing a long scroll which the user is scrolling through.

Second you want the box to be visible above anything else that's in your window, so setting the z-index in CSS to something higher than you will ever use in the rest of your code is needed. (Does anyone know if all browsers would accept Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - for ultimate safety though that would be quite extreme)

Third you need to fix the alert box in the viewport so the user can't scroll away from it - you want the user to respond so you know they have seen the message and can't completely ignore it.

Fourth is the question of blocking. A JS alert does this, but is it wise to have our own function do it and/or replace the native alert totally with our own function. Probably not, at some point you may want the real alert to work so might be best to leave it alone.

Replacing window.width with vw will make the box responsive - but it could be unreadable at small screens or not large enough on enormous ones. Fortunately CSS has media queries so you can use them with breakpoints at the most common sizes of screen to decide the width of your alert box (you need to let the height be scrollable as you don't know how much info is to be shown).

Note: the code below uses different naming from the original question to prevent confusion as the use of some of the elements is slightly different.

Moving the styling and especially the sizing decisions totally to CSS the JS can become something like:

```
function myAlert(alertMessage){
        document.getElementById('alertinfo').innerHTML = alertMessage;
        document.getElementById('alertoverlay').style.display = "block";
}
function myRemove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById('alertoverlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

CSS

```
#alertoverlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}

#alertbox {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width : 100vw;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 10px; 
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#alertheader {
    font-size: 3em;
}

#alertinfo {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#alertokbox {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px !important;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10%;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#alertok {
    margin-top: 14px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) {
  #alertbox {
    width: 550px;
    left: 50vw;
    margin-left: -275px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  #alertbox {
    width: 30vw;
    left: 50vw;
    margin-left: -15vw;
    font-size: 1vw;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="alertoverlay">
  <div id="alertbox">
    <div id="alertheader">Alert</div>
    <div id="alertinfo"></div>
    <div id="alertokbox" onclick="myRemove(event);"></div>
    <div id="alertok">OK</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can have as many media 'breakpoints' as you like - for example if you are coding for a huge display screen right down to the smallest smart phone you will need to think about just how big you want your box to be.

For centering to work (the left and margin-left settings in the CSS) you will need to have the alert box in a div which is fixed with width the width of the screen - so left: 0; right: 0;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#alertoverlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    display:none;
}

#alertbox {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width : 100vw;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 10px; 
    background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

#alertheader {
    font-size: 3em;
}

#alertinfo {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#alertokbox {
    width:44px;
    height: 44px !important;
    float:right;
    margin: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 10%;
    vertical-align:center;
}

#alertok {
    margin-top:14px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) {
  #alertbox {
    width: 550px;
    left:50vw;
    margin-left:-275px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  #alertbox {
    width: 30vw;
    left: 50vw;
    margin-left: -15vw;
    font-size: 1vw;
  }
}

#application {
   width:2000px;
   height:2000px;
   background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="application">
  <button onclick="myAlert('Read this important message then click OK');">Click me to show an alert</button>
</div>

<div id="alertoverlay">
  <div id="alertbox">
    <div id="alertheader">Alert</div>
    <div id="alertinfo"></div>
    <div id="alertokbox" onclick="myRemove(event);"><div id="alertok">OK</div></div>
</div>
</div>


<script>

function myAlert(alertMessage){
        document.getElementById('alertinfo').innerHTML = alertMessage;
        document.getElementById('alertoverlay').style.display = "block";
}
function myRemove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById('alertoverlay').style.display='none';
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try in the morning. Thanks for looking at it. It has troubled me a little. 

I guess I have a fix for most cases... but I hear what you're saying, I really haven't covered all possibilities. I'll let you know in 12 hours or so if it works :)

Comment: I'm having second thoughts about window dimensions - I will ponder and get back on this.

Comment: thanks :)  - see if you can look at that tutorial I linked to because I think removing the overlay is a mistake and the alert box will lose functionality that way. Did you see my answer as well? It works, and appears functional.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer as I was typing mine. I didn't mean to get rid of the outer div - you are right you need it (and it's probably what I was indicating at the end of my answer). I'll look at your code tomorrow - sounds like you've cracked it.  I should have used vw/vh - dont know why I didn't in all except the smallest screen sizes. I will test.

Comment: Your answer definitely solves most of your problems . But it's using %s so if the application is wide (I've done stuff with scrolling the Bayeux Tapestry....) will the alert box centre on the window rather than the viewport (ie could be out of view).Sorry I haven't tried this to verify yet. I have updated my answer which has become more of a discursive answer to an exam question than just to your immediate question, but it does keep the alert within the viewport. And obviously there's more styling that can be done.

Comment: Thanks for that. I appreciate your looking. I guess with my current experience I am quite happy with the fix and outcome and it probably does solve most problems. I have written it into the readme as such and hopefully this can be adjusted as my knowledge increases.

Comment: Yes, I think the simple solutions often work best in practical situations. And the question of whether you want to block the flow or not is a tricky one, ie to really emulate the built in alert or not. (but I like my solution for cutting down on the JS and trying to keep the alert box viewable!).

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This part is the function

```
    $.fn.CustomAlert = function (options, callback) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            message: null,
            detail: null,
            yesno: false,
            okaytext: null,
            yestext: null,
            notext: null
        }, options);
     ....
     ....
```

As you can see it takes a few parameters. 1) Is the message that will be centered. 2) Message detail(optional that will be aligned to the left. 3) yesno is either true or false. True for confirmation dialog or false for just an ok dialog. 4) okaytext is usually "Okay" or "Continue" if yesno is false. 5) yestext is usually "Yes" if yesno is true. 6) notext is usually "No if yesno is true.
All are optional but with a little logic you will figure out what to pass when.
The following is the click event and then the function call.

```
    $("#yn").click(function(){
        $().CustomAlert({message: "<div style='text-align: left;'><p><b>Confirmation Alert</b></p></div>",
                       yestext: "Yes",
                       notext: "No",
                       yesno: true},
                       function(success){
                           if (success) {
                               null;
                               // Do something
                           } else {
                               null;
                               // Do something else
                               
                       };
        });
    });
```

$("#yn").click(function(){ // This is the event when that anchor with the id of "yn" is clicked. By the parameters you can also see that it is confirmation dialog.
Make sense?

I recommend spending a little time learning JQuery. It is not so difficult and very powerful. It saves you a lot of coding. Took me less then a day, and that just from w3schoole. Try not using the plugins and JQuery UI. Rather write your own plugins as I did. This code is all from my lib. It just helps to understand it better. Also I do not recommend using bootstrap, not that there is anything wrong with it, but doing your own CSS3 stylesheets empowers you to what you want. That is just my opinion.